# Haskell floor function returns different results

Tags: haskell

I have a problem concerning Haskell `floor` function - it's supposed to return "the greatest integer not greater than the argument" but the expression

`floor 3.9999999999999999`

returns 4 rather than 3. It may have something to do with `Double` type precision but then it shouldn't compile given the importance of Haskell type safety, anyway in this case it returns the number greater than the argument which contradicts its definition.

Comment: No matter how many bits your floating point number format has, it is finite and will round constants it can not accurately represent. It seems to be that `3.9999999999999999` is rounded to `4.0` when it is converted to a double even before `floor` sees it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> in this case it returns the number greater than the argument which contradicts its definition.

It returns a number equal to its argument. As you said, it's about double precision. The numbers 3.9999999999999999 and 4 are simply equal to each other under 64-bit floating point rules.

> but then it shouldn't compile given the importance of Haskell type safety

The problem is that Fractional literals like that have the polymorphic type `Fractional a => a`. That is they don't have to be doubles. For example, you could write `floor (3.9999999999999999 :: Rational)`, which will correctly return 3 because 3.9999999999999999 can be represented as a `Rational` without any loss in precision.

If Haskell made it an error to write `3.9999999999999999`, then you also wouldn't be able to write `3.9999999999999999 :: Rational`, which would be bad. So since a `Fractional` literal can be represented using many different types, some of which have infinite precision, it would be a big mistake for Haskell to restrict the number of legal `Fractional` literals based on `Double`'s limitations.

One might argue that Haskell should restrict `3.9999999999999999` when used as a `Double`, but not when used a `Rational`. However this would require instances of the `Fractional` type class to declare information about their precision (so that Haskell can use that information to decide whether a given literal is valid for that type), which it currently does not and which would be difficult (or impossible) to implement in a general, efficient and user-friendly manner (taking into account that the term "precision" can mean quite different things depending on whether we're talking about floating point numbers or fixed point numbers and whether they use base 2 or 10 (or anything else) to represent the numbers - either of which would be possible for instances of the `Fractional` type class).

Answer (score 9):

This is not related to type safety. Check the value on http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/ for example. The values of `3.9999999999999999` and `4` are exactly the same for floating point numbers if length is shorter or equal to 64 bits. The value you get back is not larger - it's exactly the same.

If you need such high precision, have a look at http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Libraries_and_tools/Mathematics#Arbitrary_precision

Comment: I think the point was that if the user tries to write a `Double` that can't actually be correctly represented as a `Double` and the compiler allows that, then that's a sort of type error that the compiler did not catch.

Comment: @sepp2k: if you want that to be a compile error, you should know what implications that would have. `0.1`, for instance, can't be accurately represented by a Double (or any binary floating point format iirc). But making `(0.1 :: Double)` a compile error would imho be unpractical.

Comment: @tauli I don't want anything, I was explaining (my interpretation of) the OP's point. Also I think in this context, we can define "a literal that can accurately represented as a Double" to mean "a number whose string representation will be equivalent to the literal", which would lead to somewhat useful rules about which literals would be accepted and which wouldn't.

Comment: Requiring `Double` literals to be exactly representable will be a little annoying.  When you want `0.1` you'll have to write `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`.